# Azure tables in C# - how to mimic multiple inheritance

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm leveraging Azure tables to store data for a website (fast, cheap etc).  One of the drawbacks seems to be the need to reflect the data persistence in the object model.  What I've done is built a logical model, let's say place, but then multiple physical models of that needed for fast look-ups.  Ex: Place as a logical item, but user-place, date-place etc as the partition key so I can quickly retrieve those for display (ex: just grab all a users places for a particular date with one query to the partition key).

What's been troubling me is the redundancy and errors it causes in needing to maintain the same methods and fields across each of these physical representations.  The TableEntity is required to be inherited so that doesn't allow me to simply use the logical model to be inherited across all it's physical representations.

C# doesn't support multiple inheritance so how does one get around this?

Comment: Ok, I think I have resolved this so leaving it for the benefit of anyone else who may be early in their understanding as I am.  I have the inheritance chain backwards, very simple.  I need a base class with the common elements to inherit from TableEntity.  Then all the ancestors will gain the ability to persist the base elements plus any additional elements they add specific to their use.  This allows me to work with the base class as a logical class while persisting views of that class as physical representations that are quickly retrieved but handled in a common way as the base class.